# Print Number After using div and mod -not working MASM

Tags: assembly, sum, division, masm32

I'm trying to write a program that get a String that contains number, and put in Sum2 variable the sum of the digits of the number that the function got. this is what I wrote but It doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
.386 
.MODEL Flat, STDCALL 
option casemap:none 

SomeFunc proto :DWORD

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data

    Sum2 dd ?
    stop db 0
    fmt db '%s',0

.code

SomeFunc proc Number:DWORD
    Lop:
        mov eax,Number
        mov ebx,'10'
        xor edx,edx
        div ebx
        add Sum2,edx
        mov Number,eax
        cmp Number,0
        jna Lop
    ret
SomeFunc endp

start:
    invoke SomeFunc,'123'
    invoke crt_printf,offset Sum2,offset fmt
end start
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work and how do I make it work.
can someone explain me?
Sorry for my bad english.
thanks for the help.

Comment: Define exactly what _"It doesn't work"_ means.

Comment: @Michael  - It does'nt output the correct number, and it crashing after a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concentrating on *SomeFunc*

- You should clear *Sum2* before using this function. Without doing so you can only hope to be lucky 1 time.
- You want to divide by **10** and not by a string '10'
- You need to continue the loop for as long as EAX is not zero.

Applying all of this gives:

```
SomeFunc proc Number:DWORD
  mov Sum2, 0
  mov eax, Number
  mov ebx, 10
 Lop:
  xor edx, edx
  div ebx
  add Sum2, edx
  mov Number, eax
  cmp eax, 0
  jne Lop
  ret
SomeFunc endp
```

Do note that *SomeFunc* expects a number whereas `invoke SomeFunc,'123'` passes a pointer to a 3-character string.

Comment: ha thanks, but I already fixed it by working with ollydbg.
but thanks anyway , I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: `invoke SomeFunc,'123'` will transform '123' to an integer: 0x00313233 (decimal: 3224115) and pass that integer.

Answer (score 3):

To eliminate the crash:

1) Presumable you want to print a number and not a string. So change

```
fmt db '%s',0
```

to

```
fmt db '%d',0
```

2) Change the wrong order and the wrong offset in

```
invoke crt_printf,offset Sum2,offset fmt   ; this would be in C: printf (&Sum2,&fmt);
```

to

```
invoke crt_printf, offset fmt, Sum2
```

3) Add an exit at the end:

```
invoke crt_exit, 0
```

BTW: I guess `SomeFunc` won't do what you want. But there are too many errors for a short answer. Use a debugger to see what's going on. I recommend [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/).